# fancybox related thumbnails are not loading instead it loads all the thumbs from the gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to create a gallery to load with thumbnails.Using fancybox i am able to achieve this but it loads the thumbnails at once instead of related gallery thumbnails.
Here is code for reference:

```
<div class="fancybox_container" data-project="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
    <?php
        $slider = get_field("slider");
        if($slider):
            foreach($slider as $slide):
                $img = $slide["slide"]["img"];
                $gallery = $post->ID;
                $title = get_the_title();
                echo "<a class='fancybox-thumbs' data-fancybox-group='thumb' rel='gallery-{$gallery}' title='{$title}' href='{$img}'><img src='{$img}' /></a>";
            endforeach;
        endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : true,
                arrows    : true,
                nextClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width  : 100,
                        height : 100
                    },
                     title : {
                                            type : 'inside'
                                      }
                },
                              afterLoad : function() {
                                  this.title = '<h5>Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '</h5>');
                             }
            });

        });

</script>
```

Here is the link to the gallery page. please correct if i am doing any thing wrong.

http://adi.errortree.com/residential/

Any help really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the generated html?

Comment: @jumojer, here is the html (right click and select view souce. you will get generated html) view-source:http://adi.errortree.com/residential/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here. Can you explain "it loads the thumbnails at once instead of related gallery thumbnails." 
By default for each item with the class "portfolio_item" fancybox will only display the thumbnails contained in fancybox_container with the class fancybox-thumbs. If you want to display other thumbnails, you should add them in the right fancybox-container with the class fancybox-thumbs.

Comment: @jumojer, Thank you for quick response. issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After changing

`echo "<a class='fancybox-thumbs' data-fancybox-group='thumb' rel='gallery-{$gallery}' title='{$title}' href='{$img}'><img src='{$img}' /></a>";`
 to

```
echo "<a class='fancybox-thumbs' data-fancybox-group='gallery-{$gallery}'  rel='gallery-{$gallery}' title='{$title}' href='{$img}'><img src='{$img}' /></a>";
```

Issue got fixed.